# Question about unit for intensity

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, dimensional-analysis, si-units, intensity

[image: Sunlight radiation spectrum]

The picture is from one physics textbook about treating sun as a blackbody and compare the electromagnetic radiation spectrum. Note the unit used for Intensity in the picture shown, it's Watts / (meter^2 *nm). Why is there a nm^(-1) here? I thought intensity is watts/m^2, not sure why a nm^(-1) is here, is it nanometer to the power of -1? It just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a nm^(-1) here?

It's because they are plotting a differential intensity $\frac{dI}{d\lambda}$. You integrate over a region of the graph to get the intensity corresponding to that region of wavelengths. E.g., if you want to know the total intensity $I$ due to wavelengths in the range from $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_2$:
$$
I = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}d\lambda \frac{dI}{d\lambda}
$$

The result picks up a factor of "nm" due to the units of the $d\lambda$ in the integral, and the result is an intensity in the usual units.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of intensity is badly overloaded in physics. Here the graph depicts power received or emitted per unit surface area per unit wavelength. The $nm^{-1}$ is the "per unit wavelength" part. Yes, it is a nanometer to the -1 power (which just means: "divide by nanometer" or "per nanometer").

See the list of radiometry units [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometry) for all **10** different quantities sometimes called intensity.

Comment: spectral radiosity aka spectral intensity - the wiki article helps. Much Thanks!